# Generate signed APK - Error:(57) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute in cardview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I don't how to solve this. It is showing the same error in many activities.
How to resolve it?

Thanks in Advance.

xml:

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/pimage"
            android:src="@drawable/sliper"
            android:focusable = "false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode = "false"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/itemname"
                android:textColor="@color/myNavigationColor"
                android:id="@+id/itemname"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="balck, 16gb"
                android:textColor="@color/myNavigationColor"
                android:id="@+id/aliasname"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/itemamount"
                    android:textColor="@color/myNavigationColor"
                    android:id="@+id/wishselling"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/eixstingamt"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkhash"
                    android:id="@+id/wishmrp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                    android:id="@+id/wishoffer"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/WishTextColor"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:rating="3"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"  />
                <!--  <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                    style="@style/foodRatingBar"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </RatingBar> -->

                <!-- style="@style/foodRatingBar"   style="@style/foodRatingBar"-->



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/rating"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkhash"
                    android:id="@+id/ratingtxt"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/likes"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
 C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ activity_address__edit.xml
Error: (57) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ activity_address_edit_.xml
Error: (56) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ activity_delivery_.xml
Error: (52) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ activity_delivery_2.xml
Error: (52) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ addressdiplayrow.xml
Error: (9) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
C: \Users\ admin\ AndroidStudioProjects\ shoppingdrawer\ app\ src\ main\ res\ layout\ wishitemsrow.xml
Error: (12) Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute
Error: Execution failed
for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. >
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '
C: \Users\ admin\ AppData\ Local\ Android\ sdk\ build - tools\ 23.0 .3\ aapt.exe ''
finished with non - zero exit value 1
Information: BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Could you add your whole xml?

Comment: can you add whole xml + build.gradle ( app level)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Remove *either* one of those and it'll be fixed.

**Explanation:** Even though these two lines seem to be different, they're actually the same, because if you look at this:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

These two namespaces are declared as the same one, which effectively means that these two refer to the same thing, and thus declaring the same attribute twice makes it a duplicate, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I removed one,  Error gone now

Comment: Thanks you  so much bro, I understood now why I got error like that in my xml.